# Change the label of GtkButton

Tags: c, gtk, gtk2

I want to be able to change the label of a GtkButton after the widget has been shown

```
char *ButtonStance == "Connect";
GtkWidget *EntryButton = gtk_button_new_with_label(ButtonStance);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(ButtonVbox), EntryButton, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(TopVbox), ButtonVbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show_all(TopVbox);

ButtonStance == "Disconnect";

gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(EntryButton), ButtonStance);

gtk_main();
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I think it's not working because you've got `==` and `=` mixed up...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ptomato is right, you are using `==` where you should be using `=`.
Your code should look like this:

```
char *ButtonStance = "Connect";
GtkWidget *EntryButton = gtk_button_new_with_label(ButtonStance);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(ButtonVbox), EntryButton, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(TopVbox), ButtonVbox, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

gtk_widget_show_all(TopVbox);

ButtonStance = "Disconnect";

gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(EntryButton), ButtonStance);

gtk_main();
```

Comment: ahh cheers for pointing out my stupid mistake, much appreciated